# Running a number of hive queries and writing output to file

Tags: bash, hive

I'm trying to make use of the DESCRIBE function via Hive to output the column descriptions of each of the tables out to individual files. I've discovered the -f option so I can just read from a file and write the output back out:

```
hive -f nameOfSqlQueryFile.sql > out.txt
```

However, if I open the output file, it throws all the descriptions back to back and it's unclear where one description starts for a table and where it ends.

So, I've tried making a batch file that uses -e to describe each of the tables individually and output to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash

nameArr=( $(hive -e 'show tables;') )
count=0
for i in "${nameArr[@]}"
do
    echo 'Working on table('$count'): '$i
    hive -e 'describe '$i > $i'_.txt';
    count=$(($count+1))
done
```

However, because this needs to reconnect for each query, it's remarkably slow, taking hours to process several hundred queries.

Does anyone have an idea of how else I might run each of these DESCRIBE functions, and ideally output to separate files?

Comment: If you are only interested in the table definitions and not the data therein, you might have some luck going directly to the metastore. Depending on your metastore you might get stuff directly (mySQL) or I heard there is a Java API for the metastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use one of these, depending on how you process the output:

1. Just use the OK line as a separator and search for it using a script.
2. Use DESCRIBE EXTENDED which adds a line at the end with info on the table, including its location, which can be used to extract the table name (using sed, for example)
3. If you're just using the output file as a manual reference, insert a SQL statement that prints a separator of your choice between each table, e.g.:

   ```
   DESCRIBE table;
   SELECT '-----------------' FROM table;
   ```